# Calculate geometry with Python?

Tags: arcpy, geometry

I'm trying to calculate geometry in Python for a script tool for ArcMap.

For the script I want to calculate area in hectares. I am trying to use the add geometry attribute (data management) tool, but it's not working and it's giving me all zeros in my output field. This is what I have:

```
# Set Calculate geometry variables

calculate_table = clip_output

geometry_prop = "AREA"

expression = "HECTARES"

# Run calculate geometry

arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(calculate_table, geometry_prop, "", expression, "")
```

What's wrong?
Should I use a different tool?

Comment: Please [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/216088/edit) your question to specify what projection your data is in and whether it is point, line or polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using keyword arguments for the optional arguments in your call to AddGeometryAttributes:

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(calculate_table, geometry_prop, Area_Unit=expression)
```

Also, I'm not sure if this is version-specific, but I had to use "AREA_GEODESIC" as the Geometry_Properties, or else I got an error.

*edit to answer the second part of your question:*

You can use a search cursor to select the records you're interested in with an SQL query, then add up all the areas into a sum variable, then print it using addMessage. It would look something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(clip_output, ['area_field'], 'soil_class in (1, 2)') as cur:
  sum = 0
  for row in cur:
    sum += row[0]

arcpy.AddMessage(sum)
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked. I have another question now. To finish off my script tool i want the script to give me an add message (sum) that calculates total hectares for only  2 certain attributes (soil classes 1 and 2). I have a hectares field and a field that give soil classes 1 to 5.

in the python language how would i write the expression? could you give me a hypothetical example.

Comment: my soil_class field is "CLASS" so i replaced that for soil_class but it didn't work. Im probably doing some thing wrong. also my 'area_field' is "Hecatares"

Comment: Please do not ask follow-on questions in comments. Instead ask a new question.

Comment: didnt work error says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Noah_Assignment1.py", line 106, in <module>
    for row in cur:
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used